# "Various" - "Different"

Tags: word-choice

Please, help me to understand the difference in meaning between "various" and "different".

Example sentence:

> Various methods of inter-process communication are available in Windows.

Is it possible to build this sentence like:

> Different methods of inter-process communication are available in Windows.

Is the second sentence correct?
If yes, what would be the difference between the two?

Comment: Two minor remarks. To me, "different methods" could be just two, while "various methods" sounds more broad, like "manifold" or "many different". Also, *various* is kind of self-contained, as in "different from one another", while *different* has a connotation of "another", "different from something else entirely", "different from something previously mentioned". That being said, "various" and "different" *are* being used interchangeably in many situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are synonyms. Similar to what RegDwight pointed out, there is usually a connotation of many with "various," whereas "different" often refers to distinctions between 2 things.

Comment: I agree with Flotsam, the key here is that 'different' implies some distinction between the subjects.

Comment: They are synonymous in this meaning, but not in all their uses.

Answer (score 5):

For this usage, I think "various" is better, because "different" implies a comparison. Different from what?

For example: "OSX provides certain methods for inter-process communication, while different methods of inter-process communication are available in Windows."

"Different" is certainly used colloquially to mean "various," but I would avoid that in formal or technical contexts.

Comment: thanks, helpful remark about colloquial nature of using "different" instead of "various" +1

Comment: Amen. As a technical writer, I try not to use "different" when I mean "various".

Comment: @rem "Different" begs the question, "From what?" "Various" answers the question, "From itself."

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the above, but there is another possibility: 'differing'.  As the other participants say, 'different' implies 2, or something specific, whereas 'various' implies several ... but so to does 'differing' imply several.

to visit various places near to Hobart = to visit differing places near Hobart;
but
to visit different places near Hobart implies places that are unique or different in some way, like Richmond which is a heritage listed historical town, or Port Arthur which is the top tourism destination in Tasmania.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Different" is simply wrong in this context, if the first sentence is the meaning required, i.e. that more than one method of inter-process communication is available in Windows. The colloquial usage of a word does not make it correct. The second sentence means that the methods of inter-process communication available in Windows are different to those available somewhere else (presumably in some other operating system). This is very far from the intended meaning. At best, it is ambiguous. I hope that helps you.

Comment: "The colloquial usage of a word does not make it correct." Uhh, why not? That's basically the definition of normal language use.

Answer (score 0):

Various means different with some degree of similarity or some connectivity. However, 'different' means no connection at all. Although they have, similar meaning but in some statements, these two words can have entirely different meaning. For example:

I want different answers from you.
I want various answers from you.

He had different opinion on this subject.
He had various opinion on this subject.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you explain a little more, please? For instance, in your examples, how many answers are being sought, and how many opinions are held?

Comment: Different means different from what has already been expressed and it might be one or more(various). Various means several from the same speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Various could relate to numbers (like many) where as different does not relate to numbers and only to the situation or to describe there is a difference between 2 things..